# How to know which controller is loaded in outlet

Tags: ember.js

I have two controllers which both load to the same outlet, so only one can be active at one time. Both observe a property on a third controller like this:

```
App.SearchController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['navigation'],

    updateResults: function () {
        console.log('load search data');
    }.observes('controllers.navigation.search')
});
```

Full sample

http://jsfiddle.net/FMk7R/1/

When the property changes some data is fetched. If I click on both links so that both are loaded, then when the property changes, both controllers receive the observes event and load the data. I'd like to load the data only in the one which is visible.

How can I figure out which controller is currently active and load the data only in the active one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally your controllers should not know that they are active. One alternative is to invert the relationship, so that NavController is responsible for changing a query property of the "active" controller.

** UPDATE - Adding example based on comment **

```
App.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
      this.controllerFor('navigation').set('active', controller);
  }
});

App.ImagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
      this.controllerFor('navigation').set('active', controller);
  }
});

App.SearchController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  loadResults: function (query) {
    console.log('loading web search data for: ', query);
  }
});

App.ImagesController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  loadResults: function (query) {
    console.log('loading image search data for: ', query);
  }
});

App.NavigationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  search: '',
  active: null,
  searchDidChange: function() {
    this.get('active').loadResults(this.get('search'));
  }.observes('search', 'active')
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/F3uFp/1/

Another alternative is to use computed properties instead. Ember will only refresh computed properties that are actually required to render the active view. For example:

```
    App.SearchController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
        needs: ['navigation'],
        results: function () {
           console.log('loading web search data');
           return("web search results");
        }.property('controllers.navigation.search')
    });
```

See updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZTnmp/

http://jsfiddle.net/FMk7R/1/

Comment: You mentioned I could invert the relationship, how can I do that? I mean how can I get active controller in NavigationController?

Comment: `needs: ['active']` in the `NavigationController`, and then you have `controllers.active`.

Comment: Define a property (say, 'active') on `NavigationController` which is set from setupController hook on `SearchRoute` and `ImagesRoute`, for example: `this.controllerFor('navigation').set('active', controller);`  - then you can observe changes to the search field from within `NavigationController` and call the appropriate methods on whichever controller is active.

Comment: @Wildhoney The `needs: ['active']` didn't work for me. I tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZTnmp/2/

Comment: I don't know why I always thought that setupController only ran once at start. It seems a bit wierd that this is not supported with something similar to what @Wildhoney described... I mean so you could know what is currently loaded.